# Android null pointer exception while passing value to another application

Tags: android

```
public String name, email, phone;
NotificationCompat.Builder notification1;

Button aprv;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

    aprv=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnapp);
    Bundle bundle=getIntent().getExtras();

    name=bundle.getString("Name");.......................##
    email=bundle.getString("Email");
    phone=bundle.getString("Phone");

    TextView textView1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv1);
    TextView textView2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv2);
    TextView textView3=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv3);
    textView1.setText(name);
    textView2.setText(email);
    textView3.setText(phone);
```

Null pointer exception shown in the line with hashtags.

Here's the intent code in another activity. I set the manifest correctly.

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.user.adminapp.Main2Activity");
intent.putExtra("Name", name);
intent.putExtra("Email", email);
intent.putExtra("Phone", phone);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: can you show your error logs!!

Comment: Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android-application

Comment: can you please share entire activity along with error log

Comment: Process: com.example.user.adminapp, PID: 11571 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.user.adminapp/com.example.user.adminapp.Main2Activity}: java.lang.NullPointerException at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2436) at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2498) at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:179) at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:132

Comment: 4) at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146) at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5641) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1288) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1104) at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at com.example.user.adminapp.Main2Activity.onCreate(Main2Activity.java400)             at

Comment: :30) at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5484) at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093) at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2

Comment: please check the answer its working for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it may work for you,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(YOUR_ACTIVITY.this,Main2Activity.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

Activity which you are opening through another application Suppose its Name is Main2Activity.java

Step 1:

AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <activity android:name="com.example.user.adminapp.Main2Activity">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.user.SOMETHING_USEFUL"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

your Intent

```
 Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.user.SOMETHING_USEFUL");
        intent.putExtra("Name", name);
        intent.putExtra("Email", email);
        intent.putExtra("Phone", phone);
        startActivity(intent);
```

Your Main2Activity.java

```
Button aprv;
String name="";
String email="";
String phone="";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

    aprv=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnapp);
    if(getIntent().getStringExtra("Name")!=null)
{
   name=getIntent().getStringExtra("Name");
email=getIntent().getStringExtra("Email");
phone=getIntent().getStringExtra("Phone");
}

    TextView textView1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv1);
    TextView textView2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv2);
    TextView textView3=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv3);
    textView1.setText(name);
    textView2.setText(email);
    textView3.setText(phone);
```

Comment: thanks.. but it doesnot show the values in main2Activity

Comment: toast the values in  Main2Activity.java

Comment: Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),name,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

Comment: add this line in the if condition and launch the the activity through another application.

Comment: is there any way to post the whole gradle file here?/

Comment: edit your question and post the gradle file.

Comment: btn1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnview);

        btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
           }

Comment: Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.user.SOMETHING_USEFUL");
        intent.putExtra("Name", name);
        intent.putExtra("Email", email);
        intent.putExtra("Phone", phone);
        startActivity(intent);

Comment: use this in your onclick